# SQL Server using Linked Server to Oracle - table definition not updating with refresh

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replication, linked-server, odbc

Is there some trick for SQL Server Linked Server to update the ODBC connection to a changed table?

SQL Server provides Oracle with a view. Oracle runs a materialized query to basically make a table and refresh the table every 15 minutes. A readonly table.
Yesterday, the SQL Server added a field to the view. The Oracle users can successfully see and use that field.

The Oracle Table shows up in my SQL Server Linked Server. However, after refreshing the Linked Server, refreshing Tables - the new field doesn't show up.
Three other tables that were not changed that use the exact same process (Oracle consumes a SQL Server view and produces a table that is updated every 15 minutes) all work.

In SSMS, right click on the Oracle table and choose Script Table As - Select To - then run the query.

To install ODBC on SQL Server to connect to Oracle, there is a Java service from Oracle running.

Comment: The SQL Server's server reboot closed the Oracke Java service. This did in fact refresh SQL Server's Linked Servers views in Oracle.  
Using SQL Server's Refresh (object) from the Linked Servers to the Linked Server's views, tables did not fully refresh the changes.